# Counterexample to conditional probability with dependent events

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $X1,X2,X3$ be i.i.d. taking values in a finite set, and not constant. Is it necessarily true that $P(X3=X2|X2≠X1)≤P(X3=X2)$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Since the two events $A=\{X3=X2\}$ and $B=\{X2≠X1\}$ are dependent, I believe that it is possible that $A$ is favorable to $B$. However I cannot come up with a counterexample. Any idea? Appreciate in advance!

Comment: I am not sure that the events $A$ and $B$ are dependent. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Here is what I thought: Intuitively with restriction X2≠X1, the probability of X3=X2 will change. Would you give an argument suggesting the two events are independent?

Comment: I do not see this intuition. Say, I have 3 coins $X_1, X_2, X_3$ that I have tossed. What is the probability that $X_2=X_3$? This is $1/4$ and for this calculation we can ignore $X_1$. Now if I tell you that $X_2\neq X_1$ I do not see a reason why this should change.

Comment: Em...how can you still ignore $X1$ if imposing $X2≠X1$?

Comment: Ok, let's say that $X_2\neq X_1$. Now do you know something more about the relation between $X_2$ and $X_3$?

Comment: $P(X3=X2)$=1/2,$P(X3=X2|X2≠X1)$=1/4...how could the two events be independent...?(Correct me if I made a computational mistake)

Comment: What are the $X_i$ in this case? Whether your answer is correct or not depends on that

Comment: Your second computation is wrong. $P(X3=X2 \mid X2 \ne X1)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$. For the numerator, the event is {HTT, THH} and for the denominator the event is {HTT, HTH, THT, THH}.

Comment: @Sudarsan Ah...right...stupid me.So I probabily should say the two events (in my question) MAY be dependent...?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the definiton of the events $A$ and $B$ and applying Bayes' Theorem twice
$$
P(A | B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}.
$$
I am answering the question: is it possible to have $P(A|B) > P(A)$ ? From the equation above, that is indeed possible if
$$
P(B|A) > P(B)
$$
or, in terms of the original random variables, if
$$
P(X_2 \neq X_1| X_3 = X_2) > P(X_2 \neq X_1).
$$

**Example**
Let us consider 3 doors, with only one door hiding something behind. Let us say that we open the three doors one after another and that $X_1$ is a binomial r.v. modeling the output of first door to be opened (find something / not finding anything), $X_2$ the output of the second try and $X_3$ the final attempt. It seems to me that if we know that the second and third attempt gave the same result (it can only be failure), than 
$$
P(X_2 \neq X_1| X_3 = X_2) = 1 > P(X_2 \neq X_1)
$$